# Elements Pulled From AWS Not Being Sorted Properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I built a music player app akin to Spotify using react.js where songs are connected to albums and albums to album categories. The problem is, when I pull the album categories from AWS, they're not sorted in the way I'd like. I set up the schemas for all three so that they have hash and sort keys using the following links:

- https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/sorting-queries-with-aws-amplifys-key-directive-4c7fd14420cb
- https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/key/

Here's what the three look like in my schema.graphql file:

```
type AlbumCategory @model @key(name: "byID", fields: ["id", "sortOrder"]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  sortOrder: Int!

  albums: [Album] @connection(keyName: "byAlbumCategory", fields: ["id"])
}

type Album @model @key(name: "byAlbumCategory", fields: ["albumCategoryID", "id"]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  by: String!
  numberOfLikes: Int
  imageUri: String!
  artistsHeadline: String
  
  songs: [Song] @connection(keyName: "byAlbum", fields: ["id"])

  albumCategoryID: ID!
  albumCategory: AlbumCategory @connection(fields: ["albumCategoryID"])
}

type Song @model @key(name: "byAlbum", fields: ["albumID", "id"]) {
  id: ID!
  imageUri: String!
  uri: String!
  title: String!
  artist: String!

  albumID: ID!
  album: Album @connection(fields: ["albumID"])
}
```

I'm confused because both Album and Song are sorting the way I expect, but when I use ListAlbumCategorys (see below) they are not being listed by their sortOrder.

```
export const listAlbumCategorys = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListAlbumCategorys(
    $filter: ModelAlbumCategoryFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listAlbumCategorys(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        title
        albums {
          nextToken
          items {
            id
            imageUri
            name
            by
            artistsHeadline
          }
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `listAlbumCategorys`, which uses the default table. You do not have a sort key on the default table, you only have a sort key on the GSI.

You need to add a `queryField` property to the `@key`.

Example: `type AlbumCategory @model @key(name: "byID", fields: ["id", "sortOrder"], queryField: "listSortedAlbumCategories)`

Then you can use that queryField at the top of your request instead of listAlbumCategorys.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response! From here would I have to create a custom query for listSortedAlbumCategories?

Comment: You mean, will the amplify tool create the code for you? I don't know, I don't have that tooling installed on my current computer.