# Problems Using @queryField For Sorted Lists with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

This is a follow-up to a previous question I had ([Elements Pulled From AWS Not Being Sorted Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577775/elements-pulled-from-aws-not-being-sorted-properly)).

After following the advice given, I generated code for a query listSortedAlbumCategories seen here:

```
export const listSortedAlbumCategories = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListSortedAlbumCategories(
    $id: ID
    $sortOrder: ModelIntKeyConditionInput
    $sortDirection: ModelSortDirection
    $filter: ModelAlbumCategoryFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listSortedAlbumCategories(
      id: $id
      sortOrder: $sortOrder
      sortDirection: $sortDirection
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
    ) {
      items {
        id
        title
        sortOrder
        albums {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
```

Then, I updated my code to use that query:

```
useEffect( () => {

    const fetchAlbumCategories = async() => {
      try {
        const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listSortedAlbumCategories));
        setCategories(data.data.listSortedAlbumCategories.items);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

    console.log("Fetching album categories...")
    fetchAlbumCategories();
  },[]);
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Object {
  "data": null,
  "errors": Array [
    Object {
      "locations": Array [
        Object {
          "column": 15,
          "line": 1,
          "sourceName": null,
        },
      ],
      "message": "Variable 'id' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'",
      "path": null,
    },
  ],
}
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "listSortedAlbumCategories": null,
  },
  "errors": Array [
    Object {
      "data": null,
      "errorInfo": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "locations": Array [
        Object {
          "column": 3,
          "line": 2,
          "sourceName": null,
        },
      ],
      "message": "Expression block '$[query]' requires an expression",
      "path": Array [
        "listSortedAlbumCategories",
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I can't seem to find the issue with my query, it looks very similar to the original listAlbumCategorys but with the sortOrder added. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Queries on a table or GSI require that you specify the partition key. You cannot get a sorted response from DynamoDB without specifying a partition key.
The GSI you have configured requires you to specify “id”.
You can get around this in your case by setting the partition key to a constant value for all items, like “category”.